# BMO functions are $L^p$ Loc for all $1<p<\infty$

Tags: analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces

In order to motivate my question, I'd like to remember that if $\Omega$ is a bounded domain and $f \in L^q(\Omega)$ for some $q>1$, by Hölder inequality $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ for $p \in (1,q]$ with

\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le |\Omega|^{(1/p-1/q)} \|f\|_{L^q(\Omega)}
\end{equation}

Also, we easily see that if $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ then $f \in BMO(\Omega)$ with
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{BMO(\Omega)} \le 2 \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}
\end{equation}

Where the BMO space can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation#BMO_functions_are_locally_p.E2.80.93integrable), where we also can see that if $f \in BMO(\Omega)$ then $f \in L^p_{Loc}(\Omega)$ for all $1<p<\infty$. But I can't see any proof of this fact. I'd like to see one. Better yet, I'd like to know if is it possible to bound the  $L^p$ Loc norm of $f$ by the $BMO$ norm of f. That is, is there a constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^p_{Loc}(\Omega)} \le C\|f\|_{BMO(\Omega)} ?
\end{equation}

A reference is also valid. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $\|f\|_{L^p_{loc}(\Omega)}$?

Comment: After your ask, I thought, I do not know if this notation exist but, what I mean is $\sup \{ \|f\|_{L^p(K)}:K \subset \subset \Omega\}$.

Comment: It can be infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a norm bound like the one you wanted, since adding a constant to a function doesn't change it's $BMO$-norm but does affect the $L^p$-norm.

As for proving the non-quantitative inclusion one has to somehow manage to control the $L^p$-norm of a function with essentially an $L^1$-integral (or supremum of). Therefore something nontrivial must happen.

One nontrivial fact one can use is the John - Nirenberg inequality, $$|\{x\in B: |u(x)-u_B|>\lambda\}|\le C_1|B|\exp(-c_2\lambda /\|u\|_{BMO}) $$mentioned in the wikipedia article you cited. Using that we may arrive at $$\int_B |u-u_B|^p \ dx=p\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}|\{x\in B: |u(x)-u_B|>t\}|\ dt \\ \le C|B|\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}\exp(-ct/\|u\|_{BMO})\ dt<\infty $$ for any ball $B\subset \Omega$. Note that proving $u\in L^p_{loc}$ is equivalent to proving $u-a\in L^p_{loc}$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$. For more information and a proof of the John - Nirenberg inequality you may want to check out, say, [prop 3.6 here](http://www.helsinki.fi/~tpehyton/Hardy/hardy.pdf) or [thm 5.2.1 here](https://eview.anu.edu.au/harmonic/pdf/ch05.pdf)

Comment: I can't understand the equality you wrote...

Comment: @Onil90 It's a well known trick, called something like Cavalieri's principle I think. It's a special case of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Let me add that this estimate is slightly more quantitative then you indicated. Using the substitution $s=ct/\|u\|$, the right-hand side can be calculated using the Gamma function to a constant times $\|u\|^p$. However, this quantitative estimate only works for the distinguished representative $u-u_B$ which fits with your comment on the effect of adding constants.