# BMO functions are $L^p_{loc}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I can't understand the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922803/bmo-functions-are-lp-loc-for-all-1p-infty.). More precisely, I can't understand this step:

$$\int_B |u-u_B|^p \ dx=p\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}|\{x\in B: |u(x)-u_B|>t\}|\ dt $$

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of Tonelli's Theorem.

Indeed we have

\begin{align}
p \int_0^{\infty} t^{p-1}|\{x \in B : |u - u_B| > t\}|\,dt = &\ p\int_0^{\infty}t^{p-1}\int_B\chi_{\{|u - u_B| > t\}}(x)\,dxdt \\
= &\ p \int_B\int_0^{|u-u_B|}t^{p-1}\,dtdx \\
= &\ \int_B|u - u_B|^p\,dx.
\end{align}